# Calling image variable leaves a image place holder in IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

Calling all bright sparks, I am having some issues and i cannot find this bug fix. It works perfectly on Firefox, Chrome, IE11 but anything under IE11 fails to work.

Code attached

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Test Codumentt</title>
</head>

<body>

<div class="storeNews">


<img src="http://www.khl.com/other_files/khl/dealer-locatot.png"   border="0">


<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"> 

ImgPath='http://www.khl.com/other_files/khl/locate/placeholder.jpg'; 
ImgPreloadAry=new Array('http://www.khl.com/other_files/khl/locate/placeholder.jpg', 'http://www.khl.com/other_files/khl/locate/sany3.png','http://www.khl.com/other_files/khl/locate/manitex3.png'); 
SRCAry=new Array(); 

for (i=0;i<ImgPreloadAry.length;i++){ 
 SRCAry[i]=new Image(); 
 SRCAry[i].src=ImgPreloadAry[i]; 
} 


function Cng(sel){ 
   var selectedIndex = sel.selectedIndex;
   document.getElementById('companyLink').href = linksArray[selectedIndex].Link;
   document.getElementById('relatedText').innerHTML= linksArray[selectedIndex].RelatedText;
   document.getElementById('relatedImage').src = linksArray[selectedIndex].Img;
}


var ImgPath='http://www.khl.com/other_files/khl/locate/placeholder.jpg';
var linksArray = [
  { Img:'http://www.khl.com/other_files/khl/locate/placeholder.jpg', Link : '#', RelatedText :'TEST LINK'}, 
  {Img:'http://www.khl.com/other_files/khl/locate/sany3.png', Link : 'http://www.sanygroup.com/', RelatedText :'Sanny description and link'},
  {Img:'http://www.khl.com/other_files/khl/locate/manitex3.png', Link : 'http://www.khl.com/servlet/file/Manitex%20dealer%20ad.pdf?ITEM_ENT_ID=90292&amp;COLLSPEC_ENT_ID=38&amp;ITEM_VERSION=1&amp;download=1',RelatedText : 'Manitex Locator can be downloaded below.'},

];






//--> 
</script> 
</head> 

<body>

<div class="storeNews">
<table width="350" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td><table width="302" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
                <td width="15" height="50" ></td>

                <td height="50" id="relatedText">Please select from the company from the downdown below</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><a id="companyLink" href="#"> <img id="relatedImage" href="#"></a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
            <table width="320" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                    <td width="13" height="31" align="left" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td width="307" align="left" valign="top"><select name="Sel" size="0" onchange="Cng(this);" >
                        <option value="http://www.khl.com/other_files/khl/locate/placeholder.jpg">
                    </option>               
                        <option value="http://www.khl.com/other_files/khl/locate/sany3.png">Sany America</option>
                        <option value="http://www.khl.com/other_files/khl/locate/manitex3.png">Manitex</option>             
                    </select></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        <p></td>
    </tr>
</table>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I would really appreciate if you could add the above code into something like Dreamweaver to see it in action.

Effectively id "RelatedImage" is being called as  this collects the image path - however because the path is locating just the root image a placeholder is appearing in earlier versions of IE.

If anyone can help me out I would be extremely grateful, even if you could help me modify it so each image has a direct path rather than calling the relatedImage id. This must be a common bug but I cannot find a solutions anywhere?

Regards,
Sam

Comment: you have 2 body's

o_O

Comment: Please cleanup your html before submitting a problem. http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input